# Presence resource type in MS Graph Java SDK?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, user-presence

I'm currently trying to read out the present status of Microsoft Teams users and pass it on. 
In C# I was able to do this relatively easily, but now I had to switch to **Java**.
And that's where I run into my problems.
The **presence resource type** from the Microsoft Graph API is only available in the **MS Graph API Beta**, so in my Java application, I access the MS Graph Java SDK `"com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:1.8.+"`. But I can't find the class for the presence resource type anywhere, is there an extra MS Graph Beta Java SDK?

Comment: Cureently we do not have any sample for this in Java. Please take a look at [Get presence API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q_csharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the whole thing with a **custom request**. Not the best solution, but as long as the presence status is only available in the beta and not in the release version, there is probably no better way to do it via the SDK

Answer (score 1):

update: there's now a [beta sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java) available for java.

Also, the [presence type](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/models/extensions/Presence.java) was added to the v1 sdk with version 2.5.0